# How to force SQL developer to use imp/exp command while import/export

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

While importing or exporting oracle data dump using SQL Developer by default it is using `impdp` command for import and `expdp` command for export. But I want to import a dump which is exported using `exp` command, and for that i need to force SQL developer to use `imp` command instead of `impdp` command. And same for export.

Pleas help me if anyone knows how to in-force SQL developer to use `imp` for import instead of `impdp` and `exp` for export instead of `expdp`

Comment: There is no way. exp/imp do not have PL/SQL APIs.

Comment: Why are you trying to force SQL Developer to do that instead of using the command-line tools directly?

Comment: Because We don't have execute access on those commands. That's why we are not able to executes these commands using command- line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMP and EXP are client side utilities like SQL Loader and SQLPlus.

The reason you can use SQL Developer with Data Pump, is because Data Pump runs in the database AND it has a PL/SQL API - with which we have built a GUI for in our DBA Panel.

If you need to use IMP and EXP - you need to get an Oracle Client of your machine, and install it.

You don't say which version of Oracle Database you'll be working with - that's important. Make sure the client you install will be compatible with the source database you want to generate an EXP dmp with.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because there is no PL/Sql API for `imp` and `exp`. Oracle have only provided PL/Sql api for `expdp` and `impdp`, So SQL developer can only implement those API.